# How to disassemble Toshiba StorE Alu external drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

Anyone know how you get into one of these (to replace the drive)?

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/reviews/index.cfm?reviewid=112350

[image]

I've undone the screws and tried to put a bit of pressure on the back plate, but the damn thing seems impenetrable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got into it in the end.  Just in case anyone has the same issues, you need to prise off the metal cover on the back plate (which is glued on). This will reveal four screws, which you need to remove along with the two along the side of the enclosure. Then the assembly comes out of the front of the enclosure.

Comment: I had to "jiggle" it for a while until it'd come out, not sure what was obstructing it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody was wondering, Toshiba StorE Alu2 disassebly requires removing the 2 alluminium covers. So press/pull the plastic case, and use the screwdriver to release the 2 of 4 clips on each side.